# LOV Switcher under af:query

Tags: groovy, oracle-adf

I've a VO object that has a criteria *C1* with Attributes *A1*, *A2*, *A3*
In `af:query` *A1* is not rendered. Only *A2* and *A3* are. Where *A2* has a Input Text LOV dependent on *A1*.

I have created a LOV switcher that has an groovy expression to check the A1 value as below

```
if (A1=='Emp') return 'LOV_Emp'
else if (A1=='Contractor') return 'LOV_Contractor'
```

But this does not work in the view? I've set the dependencies *A2* -> *LOVSwitcher* -> *A1*
and auto submit for *A1*.

What am I missing here? It always is set to the default LOV. Does not Switch as per the *A1* Attribute.

Java(TM) Platform   **1.7.0_51**

Oracle IDE  **12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008**

Comment: In general what you did is enough. Check for silly errors and typos. Default lov is "LOV_Emp"? Add curly brackets to IF to avoid confusion. Add "else" statement to return something when A1 not in Emp or Contractor.

Answer (score 0):

You need partialTrigger, and you must have 2 LOVs in particular field.